# An algorithm for binary to decimal conversion and while statements

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while, statements

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String A= "10", B = "11", C = "12", D = "13", E = "14" , F = "15";

        System.out.println("Enter your nubmer/letter: ");
        char number = input.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Enter your number system: ");
        char system = input.next().charAt(0);

        //while( system == 2) {
        //if ( number % 2 != 0)
        //} 
        //I want this to be an algorithm to convert binary
        //into decimal, but I don't know how it can add 
        //the constant changes in the power of 2

        if ( system == '10') {
            System.out.println( "Your decimal number is" + number );
        } else if (system == '16') {
            System.out.println( "Your decimal number is" + number );
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Error ");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried it out, but it automatically goes into the error. Can someone tell what I did wrong? I'm trying to convert binary or hexadecimal numbers to decimal.

Comment: Binary to decimal or Hexadecimal to decimal? Also, do you need to write your own method or can you use a ready-made method?

Comment: This `system == '10'` will not compile. `'10'` is not a character literal.

Comment: sorry, hexa and binary converted to decimal

Answer (score 1):

I think you're only accepting one character for your `system`.  You'll need to accept more than one to get "10" or "16":

```
System.out.println("Enter your number system: ");
String system = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary to Decimal/Hexa Decimal Conversion

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String A= "10", B = "11", C = "12", D = "13", E = "14" , F = "15";

    System.out.println("Enter your bits number/letter: ");
    String number = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your number system: ");
    String system = input.nextLine();


    int decval=0; int bitlen = number.length();
    int n=0;

    while ( n < bitlen ) {

        decval <<= 1;
        if ( number.charAt(n) == '1' )
           decval =  decval | 1;
         n++;
    }        

    if ( system.equals("10") ) {
        System.out.println( "Your decimal number is " + decval );
    } else if (system.equals("16")) {
        System.out.println( "Your decimal number is " + Integer.toHexString(decval) );
    } else {
        System.out.println(" Error ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification